# Why does deletion of Actor pointer result in "Program.exe has triggered a breakpoint"

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, actor, rule-of-three

I'm trying to create an `Actor` pointer that points to another `Actor` object, like so:

```
Actor other = Actor();
Actor* ptr = &other;
```

And then, when I try to `delete ptr`, it results in an runtime error:

> Program.exe has triggered a breakpoint

But, when I create a new `Actor` instead of assigning `ptr` to the reference of `other`, I can safely `delete` it without any errors:

```
Actor* ptr = new Actor();
delete ptr;
```

I don't understand what the problem is.

Here is what my `Actor` class looks like:

Actor.h:

```
class Actor
{
  private:
    unsigned id;
    string name;
    vector< unique_ptr< Behaviour > > allBehaviours;
  public:
    Actor();
    virtual ~Actor();
    void Init(); // Go through all the behaviors and call their Inits and Ticks
    void Tick();
}
```

Actor.cpp:

```
#include "Planet.h"
#include "Behaviour.h"
#include "Actor.h"

Actor::Actor()
{
    win.GetCurrentPlanet()->AddActor(this);
    planet = win.GetCurrentPlanet();
}

Actor::~Actor()
{
    printf("Deleted Actor!");
    if (allBehaviours.size() > 0)
        allBehaviours.clear();
}

// Init and Tick and some getters, setters for name and id
```

I've searched, and came upon [The Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)), but I don't understand what operator is used when setting a pointer like this:

```
Actor other = Actor();
Actor* ptr = &other;
```

I think it is the copy constructor, but how do I implement it for my program?

Comment: `other` located in stack, and memory must not be deleted. default `delete` implementation try free memory from heap. and heap manager triggered breakpoint when you try free invalid pointer.

Comment: Regarding the Rule of Three, `Actor other = Actor();` is not invoking the copy constructor at all, it is invoking the default constructor instead.  `Actor other = Actor();` is just compiler syntax sugar for `Actor other;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And then when I try to delete ptr, it results in "Program.exe has triggered a breakpoint".

You can call `delete` on a pointer only if the memory it is pointing at was allocated in dynamic memory (ie, the heap) by a call to the `new` operator.

Since `other` is allocated in automatic memory (ie, the stack) instead, it cannot be freed with `delete`, so what you are doing is **undefined behavior**.

When your program enters the realm of undefined behavior, anything can happen. It is futile to make sense of the behavior of the program.